# (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established.... (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error

**(0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)**

**The changes:**

I made some changes on the server, it also couldn't connect from **Azure Data Studio**
I installed KB2979597 [enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb2979597-sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-3-release-information-25af206d-68ab-4be5-ddc9-4d2e69c7d2fb).

On the SQL Server I installed a security update and now I can force encryption.

[image]

After upgrade and configuration in SQL Server Configuration Manager
Now I can connect from Azure Data Studio, no problem

[image]

But from the application I keep getting the same error message

[image]

This is the connection string:

```
this.cadenaConexion = $"Server={server}; Database={database}; UID={user}; PWD={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=true";
```

version of System.Data.Client
[image]

I made some changes in the openssl configuration, it is assumed that I enabled the SSL protocol version 1.2

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = ssl_default_sect

[ssl_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

With this I have only managed to get Azure Data Studio to work, but I still have problems connecting to the database from the application I develop. By connecting to Azure Data Studio I confirm that the server is properly configured. But from the code I can not.

Someone help me please, this is driving me crazy!
Thank you!

Comment: maybe someone on https://es.stackoverflow.com/ can understand the texts in the screendumps?

Answer (score 0):

Within my network I have several database servers. But just setup one with the KB2979597 updates. By mistake I was working with another server not the one with the updates.
I have connected to the correct server and everything works perfectly.

Therefore, the settings made above are the solution for those who have a similar problem.

Cheers